# Mono.Cecil - change private property

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mono, mono.cecil

I have third party DLL I want to modify visually.
I'd like to change appearance of button that is available on form.
Using dotPeek I found that button name, now inside form load event handler I would like to modify that button using below lines:

```
this.cancelBtn.Enabled = true;
this.cancelBtn.ForeColor = Color.Red;
this.cancelBtn.Font = new Font(this.cancelBtn.Font.FontFamily, this.cancelBtn.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

I am able to load and modify that assembly using Mono.Cecil like this:

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(source);
var module = assembly.MainModule;
var name = assembly.Name;

TypeDefinition type = assembly.MainModule.Types.First(t => t.FullName == "SimpleEditor.MainDialog");

MethodDefinition method = type.Methods.First(m => m.Name == "Main_Load");

ILProcessor procesor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();
var firstInstruction = procesor.Body.Instructions.First();

MethodInfo writeLineMethod = typeof (Debug).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] {typeof (string)});
var writeLine = assembly.MainModule.Import(writeLineMethod);

var callWriteLine = procesor.Create(Mono.Cecil.Cil.OpCodes.Call, writeLine);

const string sentence = @"MONO.CECIL rocks!";
var insertSentence = procesor.Create(Mono.Cecil.Cil.OpCodes.Ldstr, sentence);

procesor.InsertBefore(firstInstruction, insertSentence);
procesor.InsertAfter(insertSentence, callWriteLine);

assembly.Write(source);
```

But all I can do right now is adding `Debug.WriteLine("MONO.CECIL rocks!")` at beginning of Main_Load method.

I'd like to change that method from:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetupEverything();
}
```

to:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cancelBtn.Enabled = true;
    this.cancelBtn.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    this.cancelBtn.Font = new Font(this.cancelBtn.Font.FontFamily, this.cancelBtn.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    SetupEverything();
}
```

How can I do that with Mono.Cecil?
I wasn't able to find much information's about Mono.Cecil online so I don't know how to get properties (controls) and change their properties (for example Font).

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 static void ChangeButtonProperties()
 {
     // Load the assembly and the main module
     string assemblyPath = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\ClassLibrary1.dll";
     var mainModule = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath).MainModule;

     // Get the method to change
     TypeDefinition type = mainModule.Types.First(t => t.Name == "Test");
     MethodDefinition method = type.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "Main_Load");

     // Get the instance field of the button
     FieldDefinition btnField = type.Fields.Single(f => f.Name == "_btn");
     var controlType = mainModule.Import(typeof(Control));

     // Import relevant types
     var colorType = mainModule.Import(typeof(Color));
     var fontType = mainModule.Import(typeof(Font));
     var fonFamilyType = mainModule.Import(typeof(FontFamily));

     // Get the setters of the requested properties
     MethodDefinition setEnabled = controlType.Resolve().Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "set_Enabled");
     MethodReference setEnabledRef = mainModule.Import(setEnabled);
     MethodDefinition setForeColor = controlType.Resolve().Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "set_ForeColor");
     MethodReference setForeColorRef = mainModule.Import(setForeColor);
     MethodDefinition setFont = controlType.Resolve().Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "set_Font");
     MethodReference setFontRef = mainModule.Import(setFont);
     // Get the Font constructor. Maybe you can think of a better way
     MethodDefinition fontCtor =
         fontType.Resolve().Methods.Single(
             m => m.IsConstructor &&
             m.Parameters.Count == 4 &&
             m.Parameters[0].ParameterType.Name == "FontFamily");
     MethodReference fontCtorRef = mainModule.Import(fontCtor);

     // Get the getters of the requested properties
     var getRedColor = colorType.Resolve().Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "get_Red");
     MethodReference getRedColorRef = mainModule.Import(getRedColor);
     var getFont = controlType.Resolve().Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "get_Font");
     MethodReference getFontRef = mainModule.Import(getFont);
     var getFontSize = fontType.Resolve().Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "get_Size");
     MethodReference getFontSizeRef = mainModule.Import(getFontSize);
     var getFontFamily = fontType.Resolve().Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "get_FontFamily");
     MethodReference getFontFamilyRef = mainModule.Import(getFontFamily);

     // I clear just for the example. 
     // You can keep the instructions and enter the new one before\after
     method.Body.Instructions.Clear();
     ILProcessor processor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();

     LoadInstanceField(processor, btnField);
     // Set Enabled to true
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, setEnabledRef);

     LoadInstanceField(processor, btnField);
     // Set color to red
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getRedColorRef); // no need callvirt here because is static
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, setForeColorRef);

     LoadInstanceField(processor, btnField);
     LoadInstanceField(processor, btnField);
     // Get all parameters to create new Font object
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getFontRef);
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getFontFamilyRef);
     LoadInstanceField(processor, btnField);
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getFontRef);
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getFontSizeRef);
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1); // Load 1. It's the enum value of FontStyle.Bold
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2); // Load 2. It's the enum value of GraphicsUnit.Pixel

     // Call Font constructor
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, fontCtorRef);

     // Set the font
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, setFontRef);

     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // Return from the method
     method.Body.OptimizeMacros();

     mainModule.Write(assemblyPath + ".new.dll"); // Save the new dll
 }

 static void LoadInstanceField(ILProcessor processor, FieldDefinition field)
 {
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Load this
     processor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field); // Load button field
 }
```

IL of `Main_Load` before:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ret
```

And after:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldfld class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Button ClassLibrary1.Test::_btn
IL_0006: ldc.i4.1
IL_0007: callvirt instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::set_Enabled(bool)
IL_000c: ldarg.0
IL_000d: ldfld class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Button ClassLibrary1.Test::_btn
IL_0012: call valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color::get_Red()
IL_0017: callvirt instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::set_ForeColor(valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Color)
IL_001c: ldarg.0
IL_001d: ldfld class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Button ClassLibrary1.Test::_btn
IL_0022: ldarg.0
IL_0023: ldfld class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Button ClassLibrary1.Test::_btn
IL_0028: callvirt instance class [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Font [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::get_Font()
IL_002d: callvirt instance class [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.FontFamily [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Font::get_FontFamily()
IL_0032: ldarg.0
IL_0033: ldfld class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Button ClassLibrary1.Test::_btn
IL_0038: callvirt instance class [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Font [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::get_Font()
IL_003d: callvirt instance float32 [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Font::get_Size()
IL_0042: ldc.i4.1
IL_0043: ldc.i4.2
IL_0044: newobj instance void [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Font::.ctor(class [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.FontFamily, float32, valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.FontStyle, valuetype [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit)
IL_0049: callvirt instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Control::set_Font(class [System.Drawing]System.Drawing.Font)
IL_004e: ret
```

Comment: Thank You for such fast reply. I didn't knew there is ` method.Body.OptimizeMacros();` method. Could You help me rest of properties? ForeColor and font?

Comment: I tried to ignore them because they are more complicated ;) I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: Thank You, I'll wait patiently :)

Comment: @Misiu Check now please

Comment: I've tried Your code but I always got errors even when trying to set enabled propert. I had to add `method.Body.Variables.Clear();method.Body.Instructions.Clear();method.Body.ExceptionHandlers.Clear();` I've also added `method.Body.SimplifyMacros();` at start, but I'm not sure if I need it. Could You clarify that? Maybe there is easier way to clear entirely method body? Now I must use 3 methods. BTW awesome code and knowledge :)

Comment: @Misiu Thanks:) About the `Clear` and `SimplifyMacros`, you don't must to add it. It depend on the method that you want to change. In the end your IL must be valid and therefore there is a change that you need them. In general, `SimplifyMacros` do the opposite of `OptimizeMacros`. It take all the short form instructions to regular instructions. i.e. Ldarg_0 to Ldarg, 0. If you want me to help on specific error, please update the question.

Comment: Thank You for fast reply. This is enough for this question. I'll check setting font and color and were done :) if I'll have other errors I'll post them as separate questions. So I can call `OptimizeMacros` at end just before I save changes?

Comment: @Misiu Yes sure. The `SimplifyMacros` is necessary if the original method was small or with small number of parameters\local variables and now its became big. But after you done you can call `OptimizeMacros` to optimize where it's possible.